# java - parse number formatted as string to byte/short/integer/long

Tags: java, parsing, numbers, antlr, antlr4

I am parsing a simple positive number with ANTLR:

```
NUMBER : ('0'..'9')+;
```

What is the recommended approach to parse this number in either a

```
byte (8 bits)
short (16 bits)
int (32 bits)
long (64 bits)
BigInteger (x bits)
```

? That is, for example, if the number fits in a `short`, I prefer to allocate a `short`, and not an `integer`, a `long` or a `BigInteger`.

This should be as efficient as possible. For that reason, I am hesistant to first try as a `byte`, then as a `short`, ... where an exception means that the next type should be tried.

Comment: What would you pass that into, when you've parsed it into the smallest type?  Really, it doesn't make much much sense to try parsing into smaller primitives.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know beforehand what will be done with the numbers, and to which components it will be passed. Therefore, I thought it made sense to allocate as less memory as possible.

Comment: That's only going to be counterproductive, especially given that most ways of passing it out to other APIs will take the same amount of memory whether you write a byte, short, or an int.  Read http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization , and stop trying to optimize in advance.

Comment: Thanks for tip, I will take in consideration.

Answer (score 0):

If your target is Java, then it doesn't make any sense to parse a primitive type since the target language handles these efficiently.  So I would suggest just defining the primitive types if you'd like to capture each token in your language application.  A big integer should probably be handled as a reference type (parser rule) if your target is in Java.  If you have a different target language, then it might have different context.

```
primitiveType
    :   'boolean'
    |   'char'
    |   'byte'
    |   'short'
    |   'int'
    |   'long'
    |   'float'
    |   'double'
    ;
```